# IndexError occurs when list is not out of range

Tags: python, index-error

A function keeps returning an IndexError when it shouldn't be while iterating through a list of 2 values.

IO'm in the process of creating a simple shell for a game I'm working on and my cd function is acting a little strange.  The default "directory" for this shell includes a "home" and an "other" directory.  I can cd to "other" and ".." just fine, but for some reason, when I try to cd into "home," the error is thrown.  Worst-case scenario, I can always just use exception-handling, but I'd like to reserve that as a last resort.

So far, I've included several print statements to determine the length of the list returning the error as well as print statements inside the loop to determine which iteration the error is thrown on. Additionally, this error only occurs with one of the list values, "home." Also, when exception handling is used, the cd command works! But I'd really like to find the root of the issue as opposed to covering it up with an Except:.

Here's the cd function in question:

```
def cd(self, args):
    if len(args) > 1:
        print("\033[94mToo many arguments\033[0m")
    elif args[0] == "..":
        if self.cwd.root != True:
            self.cwd = self.cwd.parent
    else:
        for i in range(len(self.cwd.contents)):
            if self.cwd.contents[i].name == args[0]:
                self.cwd = self.cwd.contents[i]
```

What I'd expect is for my cwd to change to "home" without an IndexError.  Here is the error I encountered:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 160, in <module>
    method(args[1:])
  File "main.py", line 90, in cd
    if str(self.cwd.contents[i].name) == str(args[0]):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: If you're getting an IndexError, the index is out of range. You're reassigning `self.cwd` inside the loop though, which seems sketchy. Can you guarantee that every `contents` is exactly the same length?

Comment: `self.cwd = self.cwd.contents[i]` is changing `self.cwd.contents`, and apparently its length is changing.  Try printing `self.cwd.contents` before and after each assignment to see for yourself.

Comment: There's no call to `str()` in the code, how is that showing up in the traceback? Please post the same code that produced the error.

Comment: You're absolutely right! When I found the contents of the directory that match the argument, I forgot to break from the for loop.  Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score -2):

1. Are you sure it's `self.cwd.contents[i]` that is a problem ? It may be `args[0]`
2. If it's the case, could you replace the faulty code to ensure the content of `self.cwd.contents` or something like:

```
for i in range(len(self.cwd.contents)):
    print(self.cwd.contents)
```

3. Also, are you sure you are at the right place ?

Your code says:

`if self.cwd.contents[i].name == args[0]:`

but your stacktrace says:

`if str(self.cwd.contents[i].name) == str(args[0]): (additional str())`

4. Finally, replacing the content of `self.cwd` may cause problems.

These are the most probable causes of problem. Hope that helps.